# How to use Kernel PCA with neural network

Tags: machine-learning, pca, pattern-recognition

My data set has a training set of 1000 input with 6 features. (data set size is 1000*6). I applied KPCA to the data set and reduced the number of features to 3. It means the dimension of the eignvector matrix now is 1000*3. I used the reduced data set to train a neural network. After training the network, now ,lets imagine that i would like to classify a new data(which has 1*6 size). Obviously i have to convert it to a 1*3 data and then present it to the network, but i don't know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Kernel PCA starts by calculating the kernel matrix `K` with the entries

```
K_{ij} = KernelFunction(x_i, x_j).
```

`K` is a `1000 x 1000` matrix in your case. Next, one diagonalizes the matrix to obtain the decomposition

```
K = W S W^T
```

(In practice one would perform a dual PCA as that leads to smaller dimension, but that is not important here as you already have obtained the reduction).

Reducing the dataset now corresponds to retaining only the three largest entries in the diagonal matrix of eigenvectors `S` and neglecting all others (-- your kernel is well chosen if this approximation is justified).

Effectively, this means that in the projection matrix `W^T` only the first `L=3` rows are retained. Call the reduced matrix `W_L` which has dimension `1000 x 3`. Now "reducing" the number of features correspons to working with the matrix

```
K_L = K W_L
```

which as well has dimension `1000 x 3`. These rows are used as input to train the neural net.

Let's come to your question: **How to treat a new feature vector `y`?**

- First, calculate a vector `k` with elements `k_i = KernelFunction(x_i, y)`.
- Second, map that vector onto the KPCA subspace by calculating `k_L = k W_L` -- which is a vector of dimension `1 x 3`.
- Finally, feed the vector `k_L` into your Neural Network and use the prediction.

Answer (score 0):

You need to project your data onto your reduced space. How exactly - depends on a particular implementation of KPCA, for example in python and scikit-learn you would do

```
[...]
kpca = KPCA(n_components=3)
kpca.fit(X_train)
[...]

reduced_new_point = kpca.transform(new_point)
```

and in general you have a sequence of multipliers alpha connected with each of your eigenvalues and your projection on `i`th eigenvector is

```
P(x, i) = SUM alpha^{i}_j K(x_j, x)
```

where `alpha^{i}_j` is coeffient of `j` training sample for `i` eigenvector, `x_j` is j'th training sample and `K` is kernel used.